# History of the Guardia Civile office in Corcoya, Spain

Tags: spain, location

I have been working through transcribing and translating my great-grandfather's Civil Guard records (via [Spanish Language Stackexchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)). So far we have processed 1902 through 1912.

In several records it referred to the [**Herrera** Civil Guard](https://www.guardiacivil.es/es/institucional/directorio/sevilla/puesto_de_herrera.html) office. My great-grandfather was posted there for a number of years.

Then, in 1912 he was assigned to **Corcoya** and I can't find any existing office. Google provides information about the current office (or rather, lack of it) but nothing about the history.

How can I learn about the history of the Guardia Civile Office in Corcoya, and its location when my great-grandfather was posted there during 1912? This would let me fill in more detail of my great-grandfather's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on this webpage which also mentions Corcoya:

http://www.badolatosa.es/es/actualidad/noticias/EL-CUARTEL-DE-LA-GUARDIA-CIVIL-DE-BADOLATOSA-DISPONE-DE-4-NUEVOS-EFECTIVOS

It might be a point of contact to find out more.

---

Using a translation service the first paragraph reads as:

> Yesterday morning, our Mayor, accompanied by the Councilor for Citizen
> Security and Traffic, held a working meeting with the Sergeant and the
> Corporal of the **Civil Guard Barracks of our municipality**, where its
> operation and the increase in agents were analyzed, after the recent
> incorporation of four new troops, which means greater police coverage
> for Badolatosa and **Corcoya**.

Contact info:

Ayuntamiento de Badolatosa
AVENIDA CUBA 32 41570, BADOLATOSA, SEVILLA